# Insufficient access error when trying to change api name of platform event or delete platform event

Tags: permissions, platform-event

I am administrator in my scratch org. But when I try to change api name of an existing platform event or try to delete it, I got an error message saying that I don't have sufficient access to it.

I try to search for platform event related permission in my profile but didn't find anything. How should I walk around this issue?